# BeautifulSoup returning None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape airbnb with Beautifulsoup. name is returning None when there should be text present. Am I doing something wrong? I have only just started learning this so there is a high chance I'm missing somethi
ng simple.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import lxml


def extract_features(listing_html):
    features_dict = {}
    name = listing_html.find('div', {'class': '_xcsyj0'})
    features_dict['name'] = name
    return features_dict
      
def getdata(url):
    s = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getnextpage(soup):
    page = 'https://www.airbnb.com' + str(soup.find('a').get('href'))
    return page

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Bear-Creek-Lake-Dr--Jim-Thorpe--PA--USA/homes?tab_id=home_tab'
soup = getdata(url)
listings = soup.find_all('div','_8s3ctt')# (type of tag, name)

for listing in listings[0:2]:    
    full_url = getnextpage(listing)
    ind_soup = getdata(full_url)
    features = extract_features(ind_soup)
    print(features)
    print("-----------")
```

Comment: What url is returning `None`? Is it the `soup = getdata(url)` line or the one in the loop?

Comment: name is returning None.

Comment: Do you know which URL is causing the issue? Is it the one you hard-coded or one of those extracted from that page?

Comment: It is the one extracted from the page. I tried higher level classes and they return a value. One of the listings is at this URL. (https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/40732006?federated_search_id=61af205e-e5bb-4ad5-b6cd-f1b0bfd47026&source_impression_id=p3_1621607049_7iSENzbpy8XsdgTI&guests=1&adults=1). I'm trying to get the 'Entire house hosted by Barbarann' text.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which page gives problem. Next you could use `print()` to check what you get in `s.content` - maybe you get warning/captcha for bots/spamers/hackers. And you should check in web browser if this page works without JavaScript because `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
name = listing_html.find('div', {'class': '_xcsyj0'})
```

You are trying to find a `div` tag with class `_xcsyj0`. However when I take a look at the URL you posted in the comments, there is no tag that has that class. This usually occurs with auto-generated CSS classes and makes web scraping tasks like this difficult to impossible.

It doesn't look like the `div` tag you want has an `id` set either, so your best bet would be an API for Airbnb. From a cursory search, I found an official API — which seems to only be available to verified partners — and a number of unofficial APIs. Unfortunately, I have not worked with any Airbnb APIs so I can't suggest which is these is actually good/working.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Test code result]
Here I run the code and got the result. Please elaborate the problem which helps to debug the result better

Comment: Try out `listing_html.find('div', {'class': '_xcsyj0'}).text` may be it will show the result

Comment: This is what I get returned.

{'name': None}
-----------
{'name': None}
-----------

Comment: yes @IsaacNiekamp Please elaborate your problem so that i can give better solution.
This page has dynamic loading it took some time for loading it might be a problem for scraping